# Relative Velocity Help

Tags: homework-and-exercises, relative-motion

I am struggling with relative velocity and so decided to do some extra problems in my textbook. I have 2 problems that seem to contradict, and its annoying things like this that throws me off, leaving me unable to solve problems due to simple concepts of relativity. This is very frustrating. Anyway, my question:

In this first question : 
[image]

The 4m/s velocity to the left of the box is apparently relative to the boat. OK, let's assume that I believe this, which I don't see why at all.

Let's look at the 2nd problem :

[image]

The velocity of the box should be relative to the cart, just like the first question. The spring "pushes" the box giving it a velocity RELATIVE to the cart, but no, its not this in the solutions. Why is it different?

As I asked in a question earlier, I don't get relative velocities (its been a year, I have read several resources, I still don't get it).

When is a velocity absolute (fixed reference frame), and when is a velocity relative (moving reference frame)?

*THIS IS NOT HOMEWORK*

Comment: I can see how this is confusing, and in fact believe that the solution to the first problem requires an assumption that I don't think is obvious (or even correct...). The question to answer is whether the force, or the power, of the man is the same. Because when he moves backwards, he has less time to accelerate the box.

Comment: @Floris I think you need to rethink, instead of overthinking.  :)  The question and solution are ignoring power, and simply making a statement about the velocity of the box that the student is meant to take for granted.

Comment: @Mike you are probably right but that makes it a poor question. They said the man could thrown the box at a certain speed when standing on land. No information is given about the relative velocity when he is standing on a moving boat. My point is that it's a badly phrased question.

Comment: Okay, I'll certainly agree with that.  Definitely could be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.  Your confusion is very understandable.  But if you're careful, you'll see where your thinking is going wrong.

These two questions are saying two different things.  The first question *tells* you what the velocity is, and it *tells* you that that velocity is measured relative to the boat.  You can measure a velocity relative to anything you want.  In fact, right there in the solution to the first question, they calculate the velocity relative to the water (the stationary inertial coordinate system).

Now the second question comes along.  It never *tells* you the velocity of the box relative to the cart; it's *asking* you to calculate it.  And that's what the solution does.  Both of these solutions actually work in the stationary reference frame.  But the first question gave you the velocity relative to the boat and asked you to solve for the velocity relative to the water, while in the second question you had to solve for the velocity relative to the ground, and then calculate the velocity relative to the cart.

So any time you talk about a velocity, you need to also talk about what reference frame (coordinate system) that velocity is expressed in.  If you know the velocity in one reference frame, and know the relative motion of any other reference frame, you can calculate the velocity in that second reference frame.

Comment: Well, I see that I am working in the stationary frame in both questions, but how would I have identified that the velocity of the box is relative to the boat and not the water? Is it the "when standing on ground" is suppose to be translated to "when standing on boat, ie, with respect to the boat"?
As for the 2nd one I can see that they are both relative to the stationary frame, and that complete solution makes sense.

Comment: The idea is that it shouldn't really matter what's going on around the man's arms; in the reference frame of his shoulders, he can throw the box at 4m/s.  If he were an astronaut in outer space (with a flexible spacesuit on), he could throw it at 4m/s (relative to his shoulders).  If his back were against the wall, he could throw it at 4m/s (relative to his shoulders).  The frame of reference that this velocity is given in is always the same.  The other question never told you how fast the spring moves the box in any frame.